# Typo3 4.5.5 and TemplaVoila 1.5.5 web modul error in title and toolbar?

Tags: php, typo3, templavoila

I've Typo3 4.5.5 and Templavoila 1.5.5 installed and I got this strange problem in the web module when I select it the right content where the module prints the toolbar and the content the page title and the toolbar is always printed two times regardless of any content in the page? When there is content in the page the title and the toolbar is on top and at the bottom and the content is in the middle. How can I fix this problem?!

Comment: Can you add a screenshot, that sounds strange.

Comment: @konsolenfreddy: On the right side you see what I mean. This is right after I log into Typo3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an answer, but I can't upload images in the comment:

Do you have a special theme/backendlayout installed? The info message in my installation looks different (and ist not repeated, 4.5.5, TV1.5.5):

[image]

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling templavoila (unistall, remove files from typo3conf/ext/templavoila/ and re-install it via the EM, do a backup first!)?

Comment: No, no reinstall just update but it's not really my business any more. I'm just curious. I'm sure I can fix it when looking into the web module.

Comment: The extension Color TV isn't compatible with T3 4.5.5 or TV 1.5.5+.